# jQuery generated HTML element inside another HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Just wondering how I can use an element as the text of another element using jQuery.
Here is my code:

```
$("<a/>", {
  "class": "test",
  text:    $("<span/>", {
             "class":  "label", 
             text:     "My Label"
           }),
  click: function(){
    console.log('clicked');
  }
}).appendTo('#label_list');
```

Output:

```
<a class="test"></a>
```

Output when using .html() on span:

```
<a class="test">My Label</a>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<a class="test"><span class="label">My Label</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `text` of an element is very different from setting the `html` of an element. `text` is essentially the character data immediately contained by an element, exclusive of any nested tags. So trying to put html tags in the `text` doesn't accomplish anything. You could set `html` to nest a `<span>` within the `<a>`, but rather than setting either `text` or `html` directly as you are, the more jQuery-idiomatic way to accomplish what you want would be like this:

```
$("<a/>").addClass("test")
         .click(function() {
             console.log("click!");
         })
         .append($("<span/>").addClass("label")
                             .text("my label")
         );
```

Or if you insisted on using `html`, you could do something like this:

```
$("<a/>").addClass("test")
         .click(function() {
             console.log("click!");
         })
         .html('<span class="label">my label</span>');
```

Edit: also, when you set `text` or `html`, you need to set it as a string. Your example code isn't doing anything because you are not using a string, you are using `$(...)`, which is a non-string object (a jQuery object).

Also, for more on the distinction between `text` and `html` (and the fact that they have to be strings), see these pages of the jQuery docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/text/
- http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Thanks that's what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use variables you can use something like this:

```
$('<a><span></span></a>')
  .addClass('test')
  .click(function...)
  .find('span')
  .addClass('label')
  .text('my label')
  .end()
  .appendTo('#label_list');
```

But if you simply want to generate HTML, jQuery is smart enough to create snippets of HTML.

```
$('<a class="test"><span class="label">My Label</span></a>').appendTo('#label_list');
```